# How to check if sequences within a data frame contain temporal patterns?

Tags: r, pattern-matching, temporal

Given a data frame 'df' I want to check for each machine whether or not a temporal pattern is contained. The data frame consists of the columns 'machine' (factor, an ID), 'error' (factor, an ID), and 'time' (an integer).

```
> df
   machine    error      time
   <fct>      <fct>      <int>    
 1 M_000001   2          10    
 2 M_000001   50         120     
 3 M_000002   109        30    
 4 M_000002   40         30    
 5 M_000002   2          30 
 1 M_000002   65         34    
 2 M_000002   50         36     
 3 M_000002   3          39    
 4 M_000002   99         39    
 5 M_000003   50         426
```

The temporal patterns consist of a sequence of events (the errors) in the format: (a) (b) (c). Sometimes two or more errors occur at the same time: (ab) (c) (def). The elements of this error sequence are saved within a list in a list in a list:

```
> pattern_list[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] "(40" "109"  "2" 

[[2]]
[1] "65"

[[3]]
[1] "3"  "99)"
```

The length of the total pattern and the lengths of all subsequences are variable.

Moreover, each pattern has a temporal annotation. They declare a temporal period within the following subsequence has to occur in order to belong to this specific temporal pattern. The format is: [0, 5][2, 4]. For a sequence (a)(b)(c) that would mean: The pattern starts with 'a'; after 0 to 5 time units error 'b' has to occur and after 2 to 4 time units after 'b' took place 'c' has to occur.

```
> temp[[1]]
[1] "0"  "5"  "2"  "4"
```

Notice that temp[[1]][1] and temp[[1]][2] form one temporal period [0, 5], just as temp[[1]][3] and temp[[1]][4] form [2, 4].

Finally, given a data frame 'output' with the columns 'machine' and 'error_patterns' (a list element), I want an algorithm, which goes through the data frame and appends for each 'machine' the ID of a temporal pattern to the 'pattern' column.

```
> output
   machine     error_patterns
   <fct>       <list>        
 1 M_000001  <list [0]>    
 2 M_000002  <list [0]>    
 3 M_000003  <list [0]>    
 4 M_000004  <list [0]>    
 5 M_000005  <list [0]>    
 6 M_000006  <list [0]>    
 7 M_000007  <list [0]>    
 8 M_000008  <list [0]>    
 9 M_000009  <list [0]>    
10 M_000010  <list [0]>
```

I guess the data frame has to be grouped first, so that the algorithm only works on the same 'machine'

```
df_g <- group_by(df, 'machine')
```

My problem is, that I could not yet come up with an effective approach how to check whether both all errors of a pattern occur within a machine's lifetime and if those occur according to the temporal annotation's conditions.
Here I tried to check whether a pattern is contained within a machine's errors, not taking into account the temporal aspect:

```
for (l in 1:length(df_g$machine)){ #go through the whole dataset
  for (m in 1:length(pattern_list)) { #go through all patterns
  help2 = 0 #help variable for counting the n
    for (n in 1:length(pattern_list[[m]])) { #go through all subsequences of a pattern
    help1 = 0 #help variable for counting the k 
      for (k in 1:length(pattern_list[[m]][[n]])) { #go through each element of the subsequence
        if (grepl(df_g[[l, 'error']], pattern_list[[m]][[n]][k])){ #check whether the element is contained the pattern
          help1 = help1 + 1
          if (help1 == length(error_list[[m]][[n]])){ #check if all elements of the subsequence were contained within the grouped dataset
            help2 = help2 + 1
            if (help2 == length(error_list[[m]])){ #check if all subsequences of the pattern were contained within the grouped dataset
              output[[which(output[ , 'machine'] == df_g[l, 'machine']) , 'error_patterns']] <- append(output[[which(output[ , 'machine'] == df_g[l, 'machine']), 'error_patterns']], m) #fill the output-frame with the ID/index of the pattern, if its errors are contained
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I fear that this format is not efficient at all.

I hope I made the problem clear. Any help is highly appreciated!